# Object Orientation Types errors

Tags: oop, object, types, type-conversion

I have some home work which I am to try and do in order to try and understand OO types better. I have read it and I am not exactly sure how to go about doing it.

Here is the question:

*Write a simple object-orientated program twice in two different languages. Language A and language b.  (they can be any oo language).
Demonstrate that the Type system of language A is "Too Strict".
-- Where as the program which you have written will run error free in language b.
-- The compile for language A should raise a Type-Error-Warning for the program.*

*Question2:
same as above but I need to show that language A is "too lenient" and that it will result in a runtime-fault. 
-- language b will lead to a Type=Error-Warning
The languages can differ from the two questions*

Ok so that is the task at hand. Now my thoughts of going about analysing this is:
1. I need to find a specific type error
2. I need to find two languages which Handel the error differently?

Am I going about this correctly? Or am I completely misunderstanding the question?

Comment: No, that's correct. You are probably best of choosing languages that have static vs dynamic typing. Perhaps Java and Python. Also read up on [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) .

Comment: @LennartRegebro Ok so then in this case Java is going to be the "Too strict" one and python will be the "too lenient" one am I correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. And as an alternative to duck typing you can try in Java to show that private and protected methods cause problems because you can't override things in subclasses.